# Visual Studio 2015 error when building Windows 10 app, app bundle containing more than one package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, msbuild

Visual Studio 2015 error when building Windows 10 app:

You cannot create an app bundle containing more than one package per architecture. Value of AppxBundlePlatforms property is 'x86|x64|arm|arm|x86|x64'.  ABCDEFG.Win10

Has anyone had this issue?

Here is my screenshot of my configuration manager:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/OItnWkU.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS says that it is:

> not a bug but by design

[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6620fa86-dbbd-47d6-a801-227c732dd1de/bundle-creation-failure-bundles-cant-contain-multiple-app-packages-for-the-same-processor)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Open your `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` and remove the `<PackageInfo>` section containing the conflicting PackageArchitecture.

You can have only one section for each architecture: x86|x64|arm, looks like you have 2 for each.